# ag-grid sorting comparator at column level only

Tags: sorting, ag-grid

I want to override the default sorting mechanism of ag-grid for a specific column only. I.e. I've been able to override at the grid level, i.e.

```js
    defaultColDef: {
      comparator: (a, b) => typeof a === 'string' ? a.localeCompare(b) : (a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0));
    }
```

However, this does at the entire grid level - which I don't want. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about AGGrid, but a defaultColDef would likely be called on all columns where a specific definition is not supplied.  One might think there is an option for specific columns

Comment: @Fallenreaper thank dude, that actually worked!

Comment: No problem @wdanda

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer: `colDef` has a `comparator` property as well, so this actually works!

```js
    {
        headerName: 'Currency',
        field: 'currency',
        comparator: (a, b) => typeof a === 'string' ? a.localeCompare(b) : (a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This Issue can be resolved by using accentedSort to True from  ag-grid ver 17.1.1

```
     GridOptions.accentedSort = true;
```